# Showing every point of the subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is a cut point.

Tags: general-topology

$((-1,0] \times {0}) ∪ \{(x,y) ∈ \mathbb R^2: 0<x<1, y = \sin(1/x)\}$

Prove that every point of the above subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is a cut point.

Definition of cut point: A point $x$ is a cut point of a connected space X provided that $X \setminus \{x\}$ is a disconnected subspace.

Any help/hints appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your space $X$ has an interesting property that for any $x\in(-1,1)$ there is precisely one $y$ such that $(x,y)\in X$. Or in other words $X$ is a graph of some function. Therefore removing $(x_0,y_0)$ from $X$ disconnects it by considering

$$X^-=\{(x,y)\in X\ |\ x<x_0\}$$
$$X^+=\{(x,y)\in X\ |\ x>x_0\}$$